# Banshee won't play music after updating to ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, banshee

I was very satisfied with banshee when I was running 12.04 but after updating to 14.04 most of my music won't play. When I click on the album or song a small "X" icon appears to the left of the track number and skips the song. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Ubuntu 12.04 mounted the partitions at `/media` whereas Ubuntu 14.04 mounts the partition at `/media/username`.

The workaround here is to import the music library again.

Select all your songs using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> then right-click and choose `Remove from Library`.

**NOTE:** Make sure you don't choose `Delete from Drive` as this will delete all your songs.

Then import them again using `Media`->`Import media` and choosing the specific folders or partitions. You will have to recreate your playlists again.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is a great start, to expand on it, there are two things I did that help ease the transition.  Before the `Remove from Library` action, export each of your playlists.  After importing the library, open the playlists in a text editor, Find and Replace `/media` with `/media/username`.  Then import the playlists back into Banshee.

I had an extensive collection of podcasts that also needed to be updated.  In order to update these I needed to update the database that banshee uses.

Close Banshee.

Install sqlite3 (if necessary).

```
    sudo apt-get install sqlite3
```

Now a trick I stole from the [Banshee FAQ](http://banshee.fm/support/faq/).  Dump the database to a text file, do the Find and Replace trick again, and recreate the database.

```
    cd ~/.config/banshee-1
    sqlite3 banshee.db ".dump" > dump
    mv banshee.db banshee.db.backup
```

Open `dump` with a text editor and Find and Replace as above, then recreate the database.

```
    cat dump | sqlite3 banshee.db
```

**NOTE:** This is the order I did things, you may be able do only the database dump, find and replace, reconstruct trick to take care of everything all at once, I'm not sure.